# How do I change the color of the sea in google maps v3

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I am using google maps v3 in a new website I am creating and I want to be able to display the sea color as white or transparent.  I cannot see how to do this so if anyone knows I would appreciate the help.

By the way, the google map is of country: Ireland

Answer (score 6):

Using the Google Maps API v3:

```
[
  {
    featureType: "water",
    elementType: "geometry",
    stylers: [
        { invert_lightness: true },
        { hue: "#ff003b" },
        { saturation: -100 },
        { lightness: 100 } /* generates "white" color */
    ]
  }
]
```

---

Use the following tool to assist in styling maps:

http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styledmaps/wizard/index.html

Answer (score 4):

You can style your map with the [Styled Maps Wizard](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styledmaps/wizard/index.html)

When you are done you can export the changes via the Show JSON button at the bottom right. 
Finally, pass the resulting JSON to your map:

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(container_element, {styles: your_exported_settings});
```

Or if you need to change an existing map instance:

```
map.setOptions({styles: your_exported_settings});
```

You can also check out the [Google Maps JavaScript API V3 Styling guide](http://code.google.com/intl/sv/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/styling.html)

Answer (score 2):

You have also a wizard to know how it will work with your stylers there :
[Stylers Wizard Google Maps](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styledmaps/wizard/index.html)
You can click on Show JSON to see the code ! Have fun ;) !